# The type or namespace 'Xrm' does not exist

Tags: dll, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015, xrm

I have got an error that is

> 'The type or namespace 'Xrm' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft''.

I've already added Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll. My project's Framework version is Framework 4.5. I added .dll from CRM 2015 SDK folder. Why is that occured? 
Thanks for helps !

Comment: The version of the Framework has to match with the version of the .dll, you could try setting it to 4.0 or 3.5 maybe

Answer (score 9):

The project's Framework version needs to be 4.5.2.

Although, that is a compiler error, you may need to remove the reference and add it again.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve this problem by using the dll files as references `microsoft.xrm.sdk` and `microsoft.crm.proxy..sdk` form CRM 2013.

I tried with .NET 4.5.2, but i got the same issue

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2019 go to
Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Packege Managment Console > execute command in the console

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Xrm.Client.2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to .net framework 4.5.2 if u working in below this. And Install NuGet package - 1. **Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk** 2. **Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling** (This worked for me.)

Comment: add some explanation too.